# Websphere Commerce V7 - Front End - Replace dojo with jQuery advice

Tags: dojo, websphere-commerce, wcs

I’m starting a new websphere commerce V7 Feature Pack 8 project from scratch.

Besides performance, my intention is to have a system that is easily maintainable for the future.

I’m not a big fan of dojo for lack of documentation, bloatedness, and complexity. Is it best practice to replace the dojo/dijit with jquery/requireJS/jquery ui?  Or just stick with dojo?

Say I go with dojo, I’m not a fan of mixing libraries together. Could there be any conflicts or performance issues mixing jQuery and dojo together?

If you can mix both together, which one UI Library would you go with, dijit or jQuery ui? The websphere aurora wraps a lot of functionality around dijit, so I'm guessing dijit would be a first choice.

All advice would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 5):

This question is bound to be subjective, but I am compelled to address each of your points above:

While the full Dojo Toolkit source is large (mostly because of dojox), it doesn't have to be bloated - it's not as if you're forced to load nearly everything in it, you only actually load what you need.  The build system can also reduce most of your dependencies to two JS files (modules + i18n bundles) with very little additional work for a well-structured application (i.e. with a main top-level module that dependencies can be easily determined from).

The documentation for Dojo and Dijit is significantly better now than years ago when it might've gotten a bad reputation for it.  In addition to the reference guide, there are [over 50 tutorials](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/).

Dojo can certainly seem complex when compared with smaller or simpler libraries that don't set out to do as much, but I wouldn't bill it as any more complex than it needs to be for large single-page Web applications.  In fact, I'd much sooner say that you're likely to end up with something far more complex (and *less* maintainable!) if you start with something that gives you far less flexibility and then find you need to cobble things together to fill the gaps.

Dojo provides a cohesive toolkit including the following out of the box:

- Module dependency system (supporting AMD, the same standard that RequireJS implements)
- Powerful inheritance and mixin capabilities with `dojo/_base/declare`
- An intuitive promise-based XHR API in `dojo/request`, which can be enhanced/extended with `dojo/request/registry`
- Support for localizing your application using the `dojo/i18n!` plugin
- A full library of stylable and accessible widgets in Dijit
- Cohesive data APIs in `dojo/store`

If you feel that you don't need all of this or are comfortable rolling your own, then that's up to you, but it's a daunting task to do all of that *and* keep it cohesive and maintainable, which is what Dojo gives you a head-start on.

Regarding which UI library to use, while I can't say I've used jQuery UI extensively, I would at least say that if accessibility or flexibility/extensibility are at all a concern, I would choose Dijit over it any day of the week.

To your question about using Dojo and jQuery together, Dojo generally doesn't get in the way of other libraries.  Some other older libraries liked to add enumerable properties to native prototypes, which could potentially throw off unprotected for...in loops in Dojo (and anyone else's code, for that matter), but jQuery doesn't do that.  Additionally, jQuery supports being loaded as an AMD module, so you can even use it with Dojo's `require` and `define`.

Comment: Interesting. I went to http://www.ibmwcs.com/p/websphere-commerce-clients-list.html (Top websites built using websphere) and cross-referenced the technology stack using builtwith.com. Only two of the sites are built with dojo.  The rest discard dojo and only use jquery/jquery ui.  Why do you think this is?

Comment: Reason 1: because the vast majority of public web sites are page-oriented, not application-oriented.  Dojo is much more frequently seen in large-scale intranet web applications, away from the public eye.  jQuery is far more likely to be used on a landing page, news site, etc. because those site's aren't SPAs that require anything more than simple DOM and XHR operations or OOTB components.

Comment: Reason 2: Because jQuery is popular.  Popularity drives many decisions that should ideally be driven instead by a well-thought-out analysis of the needs of an application versus the things a toolkit or library provides.  The reasons why jQuery is popular (being easy to pick up by nearly anyone and being regarded by some as "a way to write JavaScript without needing to know JavaScript") are *not* the reasons you want to use it for scalable development of a large application.